# Can I use Desktop PSU as Laptop Power Supply?

Tags: laptop, power-supply

I have tried to search video in YouTube to find out a way to connect it. I can use Laptop while charging and without it but I want to use it without battery and without connecting to laptop's adapter because it overheats so I want to connect my desktop's PSU instead of laptop. Is there any way to do it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If the problem is that the adapter is hot, one solution would be to buy an adapter with a (much) larger wattage. To my knowledge there's no easy way to power a laptop from a PSU... firstly you have to "trick" the psu into thinking its plugged into a motherboard (google "how to jump a psu" or, buy a K-ATX Bridging Plug). then you need to figure out what outputs (voltage/current/polarity) correspond to what input you want, and then correctly adapt/solder wiring to your laptop plug. (Being aware that at least one brand has a special 3 connection plug (some kind of sensor/auto voltage??)

Answer (score 1):

If your desktop and laptop both have a USB port type C that supports 100w mode you can charge/power your laptop easily.

You may find you need to buy a specific USB type C cable that supports 5A mode.

It should be noted you need to have an extra 100w from the PSU so if your PSU isn't big enough you may run into problems.

---

Otherwise, it going to be difficult.

The laptop usually wants between 18-20v.

You could probably just use the 12v rail, with the right boost converter.  However, you will need a compatible plug to attach to the power port of the laptop.  That plug will have to attach to the boost converter.

You may have to buy another charger, and cut the end off at least 6 inches down so you have extra wire to connected it to the boost convert.  Also make sure you boost converter has at least as many amps as the laptops power brick.

Also note you may need to manually adjust the output voltage, if so do it before connecting it to the laptop.

Comment: You can't just add the voltage together, they're all generated against the common ground level.
The boost converter part should work, though the battery connectors (and internal VRMs) are probably just fine with direct 12 V.

Comment: @towe I edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I connect my PC power supply into (blue and yellow = 22v) and is working fine -- no overheating.

Comment: This probably is not very safe

Comment: you can use a laptop charger with a higher wattage, however, there are some caveats. The wattage rating of a laptop charger is a maximum rating which means that the charger is capable of providing power up to the output wattage rating and or course anything in between.

Comment: For me its safe, just remove the battery

Comment: Except if you accidentally swap the voltage and ground pins, then it's bye bye laptop